# Python modify one list based on another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:
    `my_colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green']`

And I have a 'valid' list:
    `valid_colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue']`

How can I remove any items in my list that are not in the valid list (`valid_colors`)? So that I get: `my_colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red']` (no green)

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate `my_colors` using a list comprehension like so:

```
my_colors = [color for color in my_colors if color in valid_colors]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_colors = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green']
valid_colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue']
```

[v for v in my_colors if v  in valid_colors]

> ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red']